# Is type theory complete by definition?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, type-theory

From my understanding, type theory is its own deductive system, meaning that types have propositional meanings. Therefore, an element of a type appears to be an evidence of the truth of the proposition. Likwise, we use the type $0$ (which does not have any element) to disprove propositions by creating functions from one type to $0$.

This model appears to me to classify every proposition to be provable or disprovable depending on whether we can find an element of that type. Thus, it seems to be normal to ask ourselves if type theory would not be a complete consistent theory. Is there any kind of undecidable statements in type theory ? If so, then would it be possible to express it as a type ?

Comment: In type theory, there are many different types systems (or, if you prefer, logics). Your question makes sense if it refers to a specific type system. Which one do you refer to?

Comment: Watch out for phrases like "we can find". Type theory is not about us and our abilities. In particular, it's conceivable that we can't find an element of a certain type and we also can't find a function from that type to $0$.

Comment: Your statement has the exact same content as “we can classify each statement as provable or disprovable according to whether we can prove it or not” and has the exact same defect: “not provable” is not the same thing as “disprovable”.

Comment: I am referring to dependent type theory. I thought of something that is not provable, as a type that has no elements.  $p : A \rightarrow 0$ would thus be a disproof of $A$ since it is a contradiction. Is it correct ?

Comment: I suppose the "it" in "it is a contradiction" refers to $A$. In that case, your statement is not correct. An unprovable proposition need not be a contradiction; it could be independent of the theory.

Comment: @Mechap what is $p$? If you could make a closed term $p$ with type $A\to 0,$ that would correspond to a disproof of $A$, but the nonexistence of a term of type $A$ doesn't necessarily mean such a $p$ exists.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ok. So from what I understand, the nonexistence of a a term of a type $A$ means that we can't prove the evidence of $A$. If there is also no term $p : A \rightarrow 0$ then we can not disprove $A$. Would such situation be considered as an undecidable statement ?

Comment: @Mechap Yes, that's right.